# ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter with Fragments (not support library)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I would like to use fragments (not support fragments) with a view pager, I understand the v13 library has support for fragments but I don't want to import the whole library for my project.

Does anyone know how to find a way round this? e.g an implementation of the FragmentPagerAdapter with Fragments.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ViewPager` is a Java class. It can be found in the `android-support-v4` and `android-support-v13` libraries. `android-support-v13` is a superset of `android-support-v4`, adding in some classes that are only relevant if your `android:minSdkVersion` is 13 or higher, such as the native fragment version of `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

My guess is that you think that you need both `android-support-v4` and `android-support-v13`, which is incorrect -- you only need `android-support-v13`.

You are, of course, welcome to roll your own `PagerAdapter` implementation that happens to use native fragments.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still don't understand why we have to use support libraries for basic features like the ViewPager. Is there a "native" solution for newer Android versions, that I was not able to find?

Comment: @AndrasBalázsLajtha: No, `ViewPager` is not part of the framework in any Android release. The same holds true for `DrawerLayout`/`ActionBarDrawerToggle`, `SlidingPaneLayout`, etc.

Comment: if you want to use ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter in android:minSdkVersion >=13  you must use android-support-v13, else use just android-support-v4, but don't use them together